# What does get_current_screen() do?

Tags: post-type

Codex says ' This function returns an object that includes the screen’s ID, base, post type, and taxonomy, among other data points'  . What  does it mean by 'screen'?

Coding example:

```
function change_default_title( $title ) {
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( 'POST_TYPE' == $screen->post_type ) {
$title = 'Enter Invoice Title';
}
return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of [`get_current_screen()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_current_screen/) it's a really small function the merely gives you value of `$current_screen` global variable. There is matching [`set_current_screen()`](http://queryposts.com/function/set_current_screen/) that fills that variable.

What the variable actually contains is instance of [`WP_Screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen) class. There is plenty going on in that class, but in a nutshell it keeps track of context for admin page you are currently seeing and implements functionality, shared between admin pages.